# Let $g$ be a member of a group (or monoid) $G$, then why is it that if $G$ is finite, $g, g^2, g^3, g^4, \dots $, cannot be distinct?

Tags: group-theory, pigeonhole-principle, monoid

> Let $g$ be a member of a group $G$, then why is it that if $G$ is finite, $g, g^2, g^3, g^4, \dots $, cannot be distinct?

Does it have to do with the Pigeon-Hole Principle?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $g, g^2, g^3, g^4,...$ must be in $G$.  If they're distinct, then $G$ is infinite

Comment: It doesn't have a relation with the pigeon hole principle. The above comment is far enough.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Because of closure, $g, g^2, g^3, g^4, ...$ (i.e., $g^n, \;\forall n\in \Bbb N$) must be in $G$.

If $g, g^2, g^3, g^4, ...$ were all distinct, that would be infinitely many elements of $G$,

so $G$ would not be finite.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many candidates for powers of $g$ in $G$. But $G$ is finite and all powers of $g$ are in $G$ by closure of the operation. Hence there exists at least two elements, $g^i, g^j$ of $\langle g\rangle\subseteq G$ such that $g^i =g^j$ by the pigeonhole principle since $G$ is finite. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

The map $\mathbb N \to G$ given by $n \mapsto g^n$ cannot be injective because $\mathbb N$ is infinite and $G$ is finite.